# Ubuntu 22.04 kernel update to 5.19 breaks Wi-Fi (mt7921e)

Tags: networking, drivers, kernel

Few days ago I've upgraded the kernel (via `apt upgrade`) to 5.19.0-32-generic.
After 1 or 2 days in the middle of browsing the internet, Wi-Fi stopped working.

After the reboot, a new error started to appear on booting screen
`usb 3-10: device descriptor read/64, error -71`

Bluetooth also stopped working.

I rebooted and choose from the boot menu the previous kernel.

It didn't help.

I have a portable windows on a USB drive, and I booted it to see if Wi-Fi works there.
There was a similar error (device descriptor) in Device Manager on an unrecognized device.

Wi-Fi wasn't working on Windows.

I thought it was a hardware failure because Wi-Fi and Bluetooth were just gone.

I decided to update BIOS.

After BIOS update, everything went back to normal.
Wi-Fi and Bluetooth started working again (with the new kernel).

Today, around 1-2 days later, similar things have happened.

Wi-Fi stopped working in the middle of browsing the internet.

When I rebooted, before the system shut down,
it showed multiple times the same errors on the terminal screen:

```
mt7921e 0000:2e:00.0: Timeout for driver own
mt7921e 0000:2e:00.0: driver own failed
```

This time Bluetooth didn't die, and was working fine, but the Wi-Fi was not.

I decided to update the BIOS again.
In fact, this time it wasn't an update, it was just reinstalling the same (latest) BIOS version.
And guess what... things went back to normal.

I think something is really broken with the upgraded kernel `5.19.0-32-generic`.

I see that binaries
`/lib/modules/5.15.0-60-generic/kernel/net/mac80211/mac80211.ko`
`/lib/modules/5.19.0-32-generic/kernel/net/mac80211/mac80211.ko`
differs around 0.3 MB

It looks more like a bug report, but of course, the question is:
how to fix Wi-Fi when it's gone, without reinstalling the BIOS?

Comment: Is there a solution for this?

Answer (score 0):

this is a known [bug](https://bbs.archlinux.org/viewtopic.php?id=278134)

Hopefully it will fixed soon.

Comment: As I described, I've also tried to boot the system from an external USB drive with Windows portable on it. So I turned off the laptop, plugged the drive and boot Windows, where Wi-Fi looked like having hardware failure. Turning off the laptop didn't help at all in my case.

Comment: Hi Adrian were you able to find fix?

Comment: @AnshumanKumar I decided to stick with downgraded 5.15.0-60-generic kernel. In addition, I don't get, why Ubuntu 22.04 LTS updates kernel to 5.19 when it's not listed as supported as LTS version: https://ubuntu.com/about/release-cycle#ubuntu-kernel-release-cycle

Comment: Thanks. I have done so myself. Fingers crossed that it works.

Comment: By any chance have you ever faced the issue of your screen freezing? @AdrianBienias?

Comment: @AnshumanKumar, no, I haven't. I had problems only with wireless devices.