# where is ubuntu-22.04.2 release

Tags: 22.04, lts, lsb-release

According to the following launchpad, the `ubuntu-22.04.2` has already released 15 hours ago.

https://launchpad.net/ubuntu/+milestone/ubuntu-22.04.2

```
Milestone information
Project:
    Ubuntu
Series:
    Jammy
Version:
    ubuntu-22.04.2
Expected:
    15 hours ago   
Active:
    Yes. Drivers can target bugs and blueprints to this milestone.
```

**But the following link still says the latest is 22.04.1:**

https://ubuntu.com/download/desktop

```
Ubuntu 22.04.1 LTS
The latest LTS version of Ubuntu, for desktop PCs and laptops. LTS stands for long-term support — which means five years of free security and maintenance updates, guaranteed until April 2027.
```

Where to download `ubuntu-22.04.2` as stated in the `launchpad`?

Comment: If you install from the 22.04.1 ISO today and run `sudo apt update && sudo apt upgrade` you will get 22,04,2. The update/upgrade to existing installation always comes before the "point update" ISO is released. Once Canonical is sure there are no show-stopping bugs they will make the ISO file.

Comment: Some [people are having problems with the 22.04.2 kernel](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1456030/ubuntu-22-04-kernel-update-to-5-19-breaks-wi-fi-mt7921e) so you may want to wait for the ISO.

Comment: The ISO is available for download now. I am voting to close this question as the problem went away on its own and can't be reproduced.

Comment: If there is no dupe, I think one Q&A should stay.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The ISO may appear some time later.

Usually LTS releases get a version update before a new point release iso is actually built.

But you always can install the 22.04.1 ISO and upgrade to 22.04.2 using normal update & upgrade procedure.